# How to list all files and folders present in a hard disk using batch commands?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmic

I am trying to print list of all the files and folders present in different partitions of hard disk using :

```
for %d in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (ifexist %d: (dir %d:/s >> %Systeminfo_TXT%))
```

but this doesn't print any output ?

Where am i going wrong !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Did you define the variable %Systeminfo_TXT%?
- The "ifexist" command is not valid in batch files. Instead, you can
  use the "if" command with the "exist" operator to check if a drive
  exists.

  for %%d in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  if exist %%d: (
  dir %%d:\ /s >> %Systeminfo_TXT%
  )
  )

Comment: Yes i have defined it.

@echo off
Set Systeminfo_TXT=%~dp0Systeminfo_%ComputerName%.txt
for %d in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (ifexist %d: (dir %d:/s >> %Systeminfo_TXT%))
Exit /b

Comment: Can you help in sorting the files with size in the decreasing order. What should i add ?
And if I want to print a message till the time loop is running, should i just echo Wait .

Comment: for %%d in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  if exist %%d: (
    echo Listing files in %%d:
    dir %%d:\ /s /o:-s >> %Systeminfo_TXT%
  )
)

Comment: try to post as new question, will try to answer it! and drop the question link over here, once you posted

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76033662/how-can-we-sort-files-according-to-their-size-using-cmd-batch-files-and-print-a

Comment: done, answered. Do check and let me know over there!